# How can i upload a file into Sharepoint library, in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, file-upload

i have read a lot of questions about this but i am stil confused..
I made a powerapps project where i uploaded a file into sharepoint, that upload would create a folder with a text field that would be fullfilled in that form..  And inside the fields would be uploaded, if the the name was already a folder, he would just upload into the library!
[image]

[image]

Now what i want, is to do the exact same thing, but with C# ASP.NET, i want to create a form where i send 2 values, a text to create the folder and the file to be uploaded into that folder! Can anyone please help? :) thanks for any help ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SharePoint CSOM to create folder:

```
            string userName = "user@Tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
            string Password = "*********";
            var securePassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in Password)
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            }
            using (var ctx = new ClientContext("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"))
            {
                ctx.Credentials = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
                Web web = ctx.Web;
                ctx.Load(web);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                List byTitle = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("LibraryName");

                // New object of "ListItemCreationInformation" class
                ListItemCreationInformation listItemCreationInformation = new ListItemCreationInformation();

                // Below are options.
                // (1) File - This will create a file in the list or document library
                // (2) Folder - This will create a foder in list(if folder creation is enabled) or documnt library
                listItemCreationInformation.UnderlyingObjectType = FileSystemObjectType.Folder;

                // This will et the internal name/path of the file/folder
                listItemCreationInformation.LeafName = "NewFolderFromCSOM";

                ListItem listItem = byTitle.AddItem(listItemCreationInformation);

                // Set folder Name
                listItem["Title"] = "NewFolderFromCSOM";

                listItem.Update();
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            }
```

[image]

[Create Folder in SharePoint using CSOM](https://www.codesharepoint.com/csom/create-folder-in-sharepoint-using-csom)

Then upload file to the new created folder:

```
            string userName = "user@Tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
            string Password = "*******";
            var securePassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in Password)
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            }
            using (var ctx = new ClientContext("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/"))
            {
                ctx.Credentials = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
                Web web = ctx.Web;
                ctx.Load(web);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
                newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\document.pdf");
                newFile.Url = @"document.pdf";
                List byTitle = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
                Folder folder = byTitle.RootFolder.Folders.GetByUrl("NewFolderFromCSOM");
                ctx.Load(folder);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = folder.Files.Add(newFile);
                uploadFile.CheckIn("checkin", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
                ctx.Load(byTitle);
                ctx.Load(uploadFile);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("done");
            }
```

[image]

Comment: YOU ARE A LEGEND! Thank you ! :D

Comment: Hi Jerry, the code worked fine but now in a diferent project it doesn´t work. SharepointOnlineCredentials aren´t allowed in standart .net core... What is the workaround in this case?

Comment: Hi Ricardo, answered this question in your another thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64026245/why-do-i-have-error-on-sharepointonlinecredentials-namespace-not-found/64038711#64038711

Please check.

Comment: Hi Jerry, i have been trying to make this code dinamic, with my inputs instead of the hardcoded URL and stuff like that, one thing i have been struggling on is the repeated folders.. It is trying to create duplicated folders witch leads to error, what i want to do, is adapt what you have, but i dont see anything that i can do to achieve that! 
By the way, instead of using the connection your way, i followed https://ypcode.io/posts/2020/07/use-csom-aspnetcore/ , so that i can do this on .Net Core.
Thanks for the help , i am really appreciated! :)