# Why do i have error on SharePointOnlineCredentials ? namespace not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, sharepoint-online, csom

I have CSOM packaged installed as you can see:

[image]

And i cannot install sharepoint package or runtime because it says its not compatible with my version 3.1 ...

So this is a repeated question, but the thing is i cant comment and in any other post people tell us to install all this packages i talked before... How can i use SharePointOnlineCredentials? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SharePointOnlineCredentail isn't supported in .NET Standard platform any more.

Please check the official document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard) for more details:

[image]

A solution would register Azure AD App and use this App get the access token for authentcaition.

You can refer the official document above for detailed code sample.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM` NuGet package.
You will find `SharePointOnlineCredentials` in `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` namespace:

```
 var creds = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, password);
```

Comment: That is already installed... And i worte using Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client at the top, and still doesn´t let me use SharePointOnlineCredentials... :)

Comment: How about
```
  var creds = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, password);
```

Comment: Which platform are you using, If you are trying to use it in .Net Core it won't work, you have to go the Azure AD way as suggested by @Jerry above.
You can use this to guide you - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard